# Android 2.2 - Why I can not see the event I added into Calendar?

Tags: android

I am new to android development world. I want to add one event into my native calendar, I can see the operation successfully, however when I go to Calendar I can not see that. My codes are below

String [] projection = new String [] {"_id", "name"};
                Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

```
            Cursor c = managedQuery(calendars, projection, "selected=1", null, null);

            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                String calName;
                String calID;
                int nameColumn = c.getColumnIndex("name");
                int idColumn = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                calName = c.getString(nameColumn);
                calID = c.getString(idColumn);

                Time start = new Time("20110416T090000");
                Time end = new Time("20110416T100000");
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("calendar_id", calID);
                values.put("title", "Event Title");
                values.put("description", "test d");
                values.put("eventLocation", "Melbourne");
                values.put("dtstart", start.toMillis(true));
                values.put("dtend", end.toMillis(true));
                values.put("allDay", 0);
                values.put("eventStatus", 1);
                values.put("transparency", 0);
                values.put("visibility", 0);
                values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                Uri events = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
                Uri result = getContentResolver().insert(events, values);
```

I use Motorola unit. Can anybody point out why I am failed? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following ContentValues in my own projects and been successful:

```
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("calendar_id", calendarid);          
            cv.put("title", "sometitle");
            cv.put("dtstart", ""+calendarfrom.getTimeInMillis());
            cv.put("dtend", ""+calendarto.getTimeInMillis());
            cv.put("hasAlarm", 0);

            Uri newevent = getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), cv);
```

I suspect one of the contentvalues you are providing is causing the failure. Try my simplified example first.

Comment: Thanks, I got the rootcause. It's the format of my Time settings. Now, it works.